# Why am I receiving a 'Syntax Error' when using a CASE function?

Tags: formula, compile-error

I've been looking for answers to this question for a couple days now and haven't found anything.

I am trying to assign a field a value (number) based on a picklist value from another field.

What I've been using is this formula:

```
CASE( Zebra_Color__c , 
  “Green”, “0.9”,
 “Yellow”, “0.5”,
 “Red”, “0”,
"0")
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you wrote this in Microsoft Word (or another Microsoft product); formulas do not support "Smart Quotes." ("`“`" and "`”`"). Make sure you're using actual quote characters ("):

```
CASE( Zebra_Color__c, "Green", "0.9", "Yellow", "0.5", "Red", "0", "0")
```

Also, if the field you're assigning to is an actual number, no quotes are needed around the numbers:

```
CASE( Zebra_Color__c, "Green", 0.9, "Yellow", 0.5, "Red", 0, 0)
```